# Traveling to France, on single-entry Schengen tourist visa issued by Sweden

Tags: visas, schengen, customs-and-immigration, france, sweden

I'm an Indian national, currently residing in US. I'd applied for a Schengen visa for Iceland at the Sweden consulate (Sweden handles visa processing for Iceland). My passport with the stamped visa arrived late, to the point that I had to cancel my travel.
I now have an approved Schengen single-entry tourist visa issued by Sweden that I haven't traveled on. Planning a new trip to Iceland in the short duration while the visa is still valid is turning out to be just too expensive (no flight options available). Can I use this visa to travel to France instead?

Others have asked similar questions regarding use of the single entry Schengen visa, but I'm specifically interested in guidance / experience from travelers to France who've been in this situation.

UPDATE: I made the trip to Sweden, though the visa had been issued by Sweden for travel to Iceland. Faced no problem at immigration on entry.

Comment: Technically, yes. But. France is known to be very harsh when it comes to visas. Also, it will make your life harder in the future when it comes to obtaining new visas since you haven't used the previous one as you've told you would.

Comment: With regard to your update, you should normally post an answer to your own question, but I suppose you cannot do that because it is closed. Instead, perhaps you should post an answer to the linked duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Schengen visa does let you enter the Schengen Area anywhere; however, you're supposed to apply for it from the embassy of the country that is your main destination.

So have copies of the (dated) flight ticket to Iceland, and be prepared for the possibility of having to explain to the French that you were planning to visit Iceland but couldn't due to the visa being issued too late.

The point is to convince them that you didn't commit visa fraud, i.e. applying for an Icelandic visa through Sweden knowing you wouldn't set foot in Iceland.

Comment: Thanks! We decided to keep it safe and changed travel plans to Sweden instead. Good tip on carrying dated copies of the original ticket - to clarify my intentions. Will do that.